# The highest level of significance at which the null will not be rejected (t-distribution)

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, p-value

How do you determine the **highest** level of significance (in decimal
form) at which the null hypothesis will not be rejected?

Let's say for instance I got a p-value of $0.001$ and a test statistic of $3.273$, then is $0.0005$ the highest level of level of significance at which $H_{0}$ will not be rejected?

Answer (score 0):

The "p-value" can be viewed as an empirical highest level of significance, i.e., in your case is $0.001$.